# Request focus for an editText that is in a recyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin

I’ve created a custom view that can be inflated on a fragment which contains a recycled view. The custom view is to handle some form style things for clients, so the recyclerView has at least one row that has and editText.

I’ve been trying to `requestFocus()` on the first rows editText, but I’ve zero luck. I’ve spent hours pouring over similar problems, but not yet to find one that works with a custom view.

The biggest problem I’m having is that I can’t find somewhere to `requestFocus()` that guarantees the recyclerView has been completely loaded. In fact, everything I have tried so far gets executed well before the recyclerView is laid out.

Anyone have any experience with this or any ideas I could try?

Answer (score 0):

So, I managed to resolve this issue. The problem wasn't that the editText wasn't getting focus, it looks like it was as a result of it receiving focus before it had finished being laid out, and so there was no keyboard response.

All I had to do was force the keyboard to show as part of the fragment layout, and it was good to go.